# PDO query running slow

Tags: php, mysql

I've looked and tried many different solutions, but none seemed to work.
I'm running the following query to fetch results from a 100k table:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT expenses.id AS eID, expenses.date, 
                        expenses.receipt, expenses.purpose, expenses.date_submitted, 
                        expenses.expense_type, expenses.description, 
                        expenses.curr_used,expenses.reimbursement_amount, 
                        expenses.hst_amount, expenses.amex_amount, expenses.gl_acct, 
                        expenses.net_amount,expenses.status, users.id AS uID,  
                        users.firstname, users.lastname, users.department, 
                        users.adminship_level, users.is_finance 
                FROM expenses 
                    INNER JOIN users on expenses.user_id = users.id
            )  as expense_info 
WHERE (
        (department="Publishing" 
        AND adminship_level < 4) 
    OR uID=8
    ) 
ORDER BY date_submitted DESC 
LIMIT 15
```

The expenses table is the one with the 100k rows, whilst the users table has 500 users.

The users table is tied to the expenses w/ a foreign key on user_id, and also contains a composite index on department+adminship level.

EXPLAINing yields [the following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2ebc.png)

Running this w/ MySQL Workbench works fine and is very fast. However, placing the exact same query into php and using PDO's prepare() + execute() functions takes 6 whole seconds to fetch the 15 results.

Any ideas on how I can improve the speed? What am I doing wrong?

I'm using XAMPP, but without its MariaDB (instead I use MySQL 8)

Please ask for extra details that might help and i'll provide them

Comment: don't use `select *`. write down the columns you need

Comment: I dont see the point in a subordinate query here! Am I missing something?

Comment: I've tried that, doesn't help in this case

Comment: My bad I'm quite new to MySQL, What should I do in that case? Just remove the outer select?

Comment: If you can do it without a subquery, you should. Subqueries will slow down the execution time

Comment: Also whats the point of a `prepare` you have no parameters to bind so a simple `query()` would seem all you need

Comment: Oh no in the PHP it is binding, although i took a specific case where it binds to the values provided above. The department, adminship level, and uID are bound dynamically

Comment: And do you really want to get `uID=8` and also any rows where `department="Publishing" AND adminship_level < 4`

Comment: Erm, yes I do. Like I said it's just one of the cases that can happen that I took

Answer (score 0):

Erm,

```
SELECT e.id eID
     , e.date
     , e.receipt
     , e.purpose
     , e.date_submitted
     , e.expense_type
     , e.description
     , e.curr_used
     , e.reimbursement_amount
     , e.hst_amount
     , e.amex_amount
     , e.gl_acct
     , e.net_amount
     , e.status
     , u.id uID
     , u.firstname
     , u.lastname
     , u.department
     , u.adminship_level
     , u.is_finance 
  FROM expenses e
  JOIN users u
    ON e.user_id = u.id
 WHERE (u.department = "Publishing" AND u.adminship_level < 4) 
    OR uID=8
 ORDER 
    BY e.date_submitted DESC 
 LIMIT 15
```

Answer (score 0):

This would seem like all you need to do, removing the unnecessary sub query and its overhead

```
SELECT expenses.id AS eID, expenses.date, 
       expenses.receipt, expenses.purpose, expenses.date_submitted, 
       expenses.expense_type, expenses.description, 
       expenses.curr_used,expenses.reimbursement_amount, 
       expenses.hst_amount, expenses.amex_amount, expenses.gl_acct, 
       expenses.net_amount,expenses.status, users.id AS uID,  
       users.firstname, users.lastname, users.department, 
       users.adminship_level, users.is_finance 
FROM expenses 
    INNER JOIN users on expenses.user_id = users.id
WHERE uID = :uID
OR (department="Publishing" AND adminship_level < :aship)
ORDER BY date_submitted DESC 
LIMIT 15
```

Comment: changed it, still about the same speed

Comment: Then you may need to look at indexing some relevant columns

Comment: Yeah I think that's where my issue is, i'm lost as to what to index. i've tried indexing the columns that I thought were proper in expenses but none helped. Additionally this is running fast in Workbench, so is it possible that it's PDO that's slowing it down as drastically as this?